# Open Ionic ios app and validate

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic and in a couple of weeks I finish my test project. I can test in the emulator but I would like to run it on a physical computer. I could open the way find within xcode. I would also like to know how to validate the application to upload and pass the review process. I am new ionic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do to open your application in Xcode is go to your root project folder for example:

`your_proyect/platform/ios`

And there find the file with the name of your application `.xcodeproj`.

Remember that every change you make you run in your console `ionic build ios` to update the project. To validate your application you must go to the Product tab, then and there loaded Archive your application for errors and you can, validate, generate IPA or upload your iTunes connect.

Check this [ionic forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-submit-ios-app-to-app-store-using-xcode/1795/6)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll continue to look on the review of the application.